# Font scaling issues on Web Application for mobile on control click

Tags: mobile, web-applications, fonts, zooming, responsive

I am designed responsive application for mobile, tablets and desktops using
AngularJS v1.5.8
Bootstrap  version: '3.3.7'
Angularui-bootstrap Version: 2.1.4

I am handing responsive behavior using CSS media query with viewport size like

```
@media (min-width: 786){
   body {
             font-size: 0.80vw !important;
    }

   .dropdown-menu {
             font-size: 0.80vw !important;
    }

   .form-control {
       font-size: 0.80vw !important;
        height:2.0vw !important;
    }

   .control-label {
       font-size: 0.80vw !important;
    }
}
```

And using Bootstrap Column like

```
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
```

I have added the meta tag in my Layout page

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and I have tried following as well

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Problem :- In mobile viewport [Especially Android] when I click any control of page, Control gets zoom out and webpage fonts get zoom in (font become so small to read) -- see below image.

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7YCD.png)

How can I fix this font zoom in/scaling issue ???
Test mobile device have Android version 6.0.1
Below is the image for reference. When we click on control font size shrinks.

Comment: What version of Android? `vw` isn't supported on Android until 4.4 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @jonmrich.
Test mobile device has Android version 6.0.1

Comment: @jonmrich, Click at "Click here to view image" in Question to view how mobile device behaves.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have any JS or jquery that might be changing the font when the input is selected?

Comment: @jomrich Although I'm not using jQuery but any ideas how to debug in Andrioid mobile device, so I can figure out if there is any library causing any issue.